# Is it possible to show numbers in non-engineering format in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I have some large floating point numbers such as `1243564832.75` in MATLAB. MATLAB changes the format to `1.2435e09` or if I use long format: `1.2435648e09` or something like that.

Is there any way I can display the numbers in their non-engineering format (`1243564832.75`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call the following command

```
format longG
```

Then the display should be "fixed"