# Matlab - Reading unixtimestamps using dlmread

Tags: matlab, format, timestamp, exponentiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to show numbers in non-engineering format in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999205/is-it-possible-to-show-numbers-in-non-engineering-format-in-matlab)

am reading a set of unix timestamps from a file using dlmread

say
1311120481
1311120542
1311120603

in an array . 
After reading all values are coverted to exponential . 1.311e+9 etc ... But i need the actual timestamps to use it create a range around it.

Can anyone help how to get the values as it is ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an effect of how Matlab *displays* numbers rather than how it stores them.  It has not actually converted the values to a new format; it just chooses to display them this way.  You can change how Matlab displays values using the [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) command:

```
>> x = [1311120481 1311120542 1311120603]

x =

   1.0e+09 *

    1.3111    1.3111    1.3111

>> format longg
>> x 

x =

                1311120481                1311120542                1311120603
```

Sometimes it is also useful to simply subtract some large, known offset:

```
>> x - x(1)

ans =

     0    61   122
```

You can also use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html):

```
>> fprintf('%d\n', x)
1311120481
1311120542
1311120603
```