# de-normalization problems

Tags: matlab, vector, normalization, denormalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to show numbers in non-engineering format in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999205/is-it-possible-to-show-numbers-in-non-engineering-format-in-matlab)

I noticed when applying my normalization method below:

```
%# get max and min of spreadsheet(494021x42)
maxM = max(M(:)) %# Max = 693375640
minM = min(M(:)) %# Min = 0 

%# normalize to -1...1
Mnormalize = ((M-minM)./(maxM-minM) - 0.5 ) *2;
```

That when I try to de-normalize with the below method:

```
%# to "de-normalize", apply the calculations in reverse
vec = (Mnormalize./2+0.5) * (maxM-minM) + minM
```

I dont quite get the correct answers back, below is the original spreadsheet snippet picture:

[image]

and here is the de-normalized snippet:

[image]

Notice how its almost the exact same except for column six, for some reason the output is placing the decimal in the wrong place.

So my questions is:

1) How do I fix column 6

and an extra question is:

2) how do I remove trailing zeros

Comment: row six doesn't even exist >.<

Comment: opps sorry sorry my mistake i ment column six ^,.,^

Comment: @yoda: I think it's a duplicate of the ubiquitous floating point issue. Though I can't seem to find the right post at the moment. Will delete my answer once someone identifies the right dupe.

Comment: Alternate dupes: [Is it possible in matlab to explicitly format the output numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759982/is-it-possible-in-matlab-to-explicitly-format-the-output-numbers), [how to show certain number of decimal digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759982/is-it-possible-in-matlab-to-explicitly-format-the-output-numbers)

Comment: Could also be a `class`/datatype issue, which class is `M`?

Comment: its a floating point issue if anyone can find something similar would be much appreciated for now it stays. Juhl what do you mean what class is M?

Comment: if I do class M the ans equals char if thats what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the trailing zeros, use [ROUND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/round.html).

To learn more about floating point issues, [read this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)